# Are employees of a military contractor like Blackwater subject to being tried at a court-martial?

Tags: military

Are employees of a military contractor like Blackwater subject to being tried at a court-martial? In my understanding, soldiers are tried at a court martial if they break military law, but I am not sure if the same can be said about employees and especially armed employees of military contractors like Blackwater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

I think so, in principle. [10 USC 802](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/10/802) lists people subject to the Uniform Code of Military Justice, which governs military crimes and courts-martial.  It includes:

> Individuals belonging to one of the eight categories enumerated in Article 4 of the Convention Relative to the Treatment of Prisoners of War, done at Geneva August 12, 1949 (6 UST 3316), who violate the law of war.

One of [those categories](https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/applic/ihl/ihl.nsf/Article.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=2F681B08868538C2C12563CD0051AA8D) is:

> Persons who accompany the armed forces without actually being members thereof, such as civilian members of military aircraft crews, war correspondents, supply contractors, members of labour units or of services responsible for the welfare of the armed forces, provided that they have received authorization from the armed forces which they accompany, who shall provide them for that purpose with an identity card similar to the annexed model.

I think this would apply to military contractors.